# How to create a inner border for a box in html?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

How to Create a inner border for a box in html?

**See this picture:**

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 73):

Take a look at this , we can simply do this with `outline-offset` property

**Output image look like**

[image]

```css
.black_box {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:#000;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid #000;
    outline: 1px dashed #fff;
    outline-offset: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="black_box"></div>
```

Comment: This should definitely be the answer - short, clean and simple.

Comment: `outline` is not supported in IE

Comment: I prefer this answer over using box shadow with inset, which is a solution in many other Stack Overflow questions. When I tried it the other way with box shadow inset, my figures would not center correctly. Your solution didn't affect any of my other elements inside the div. +1

Comment: best answer even in 2022

Answer (score 5):

1. Use `dashed` border style for outline.
2. Draw `background-color` with `:before` or `:after` pseudo element.

***Note:*** This method will allow you to have maximum browser support.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.box {
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
  position: relative;
  height: 160px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also use `box-shadow` and add transparency to that dashed `border` via `background-clip` to let you see `body` `background`.

example

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #1761A2;
  border: dashed 3px #1761A2;
  background: linear-gradient(#1761A2, #1761A2) no-repeat;
  background-clip: border-box;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  min-width: 12em;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, yellow, gray, tomato, purple, lime, yellow, gray, tomato, purple, lime, yellow, gray, tomato, purple, lime);
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
::first-line {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  text-shadow: 0 0
}
code {
  color: tomato;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0;
}
em {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white, 0 0 2px white
}
```

```html
<h1>transparent dashed border<br/>
  <em>with</em> <code>background-clip</code>
</h1>
```

[Pen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MJyRYG)

render in firefox:
[image: screenshot from the snippet]

Comment: Worth pointing out, that unlike using outline, the box-shadow solution works if you use border-radius to create a non-rectangular div.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.blackBox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    color: cyan;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.blackBox::before {
 position: absolute;
    border: 1px dotted #fff;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="blackBox">Created an inner border box. <br> Working fine all major browsers.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used without outline-offset property because outline-offset didn't support IE browser.

Answer (score 2):

Html:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="innerDiv">Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outerDiv{
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
 }

 .innerDiv{
     border: 2px dashed #fff;
     min-height: 200px; //adding min-height as there is no content inside

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .box{ width:500px; height:200px; background:#000; border:2px solid #ccc;}
        .inner-border {
            border: 20px solid black;
            box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px red;
            box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in element's width and height */
        }
        /* CSS3 solution only for rectangular shape */
        .inner-outline {
            outline: 10px solid red;
            outline-offset: -30px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="box inner-border inner-outline"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't support outline-offset so another solution would be to create 2 div tags, one nested into the other one. The inner one would have a border and be slightly smaller than the container.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px dashed #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```